# How can I change the login screen back to a fullscreen wallpaper?

Tags: release-juno, greeter

I just got the new greeter update. And at first I thought it was error or something got installed under the hood. Then I found this blog post, so I know it isn't an error at least.

https://blog.elementary.io/say-hello-to-the-new-greeter/

But I really do not like this new design. Specifically the tiny box of detail, lost in a field of dull gray. I do not want to overload this question with my opinions however, so moving on.

Is there any way to go back to the old style? Or at least have a background or something?

Comment: based on the blog post and other later posts, the team will listen to feedback, so you can let your opinions be heard on their github and they may consider them in future iterations on the design

Answer (score 2):

The new greeter was designed specifically to address several user-reported issues and complaints with the old design. One major piece of feedback from many users was that the fullscreen wallpaper made other aspects of the greeter less than accessible to them. Another bit of feedback was that it was hard to quickly see multiple users at a glance, especially when many users don't set a custom user avatar.

The new design instead shows users' wallpapers on cards, allowing several to be seen at once. The neutral background ensures the clock always remains legible and contrast-compliant.

We are open to further feedback on the design, and I personally have been experimenting with a [version of the greeter](https://github.com/elementary/greeter/pull/374) that makes the user cards larger on larger displays. But it is unlikely that we will change the design back to the problematic all-screen wallpaper design from before.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has not been integrated unfortunately.

After some research I found a branch of the official github which allows to have a picture in wallpaper with the blur effect

https://github.com/elementary/greeter/tree/blurred-background